# refresh apache camel routes

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I am using `spring camel` as standalone application which builds many `routes` depending on what was returned from `psql database`:

```
private void addEndpoint(String urlName, String type, String host, String port, String username, String password) {


        String endpointUrl = String.format("https://%s:%s?username=%s&password=%s", host, port, username, password);

        from("direct:endpoint_" + urlName)
            .throttle(1).timePeriodMillis(60000)
            .to(endpointUrl);

    }
```

and `route` is created in a loop which depends on what is returned from database like this:

```
@Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        final List<Url> url= dbUrlDAO.getUrl();

        for (Url urlInfo : urls) {


            addEndpoint(urlInfo.getName(), urlInfo.getType(), urlInfo.getIp(), urlInfo.getPort(),urlInfo.getUsername(), urlInfo.getPassword());

        }
```

What I would like to acheive is to be able to add `route` without restarting application (route builder is being initialized by camel-context.xml).

Is there anyway to force running application to refresh `camel context`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can add / remove routes at runtime. There is API on CamelContest to do that, and examples you can google find / read books etc.